# Ubuntu Studio 22.04: Carla 2.4.2 does not save positions in the patchbay

Tags: sound, ubuntu-studio, jack

I have a set of plugins that do a pretty good job for what I need, but fairly often, I need to manually re-patch the raw inputs and/or final outputs, usually because I'm using different devices.  Not a problem, I've organized both the rack and the patchbay according to signal flow, so I'll just go to the patchbay and do that...except that it's all jumbled up again!

The rack with everything in it is still there, along with the settings and connections, so it still works as an "untouchable black box", but it's unreasonably difficult to change the connections because the patchbay insists on being "a mess of spaghetti" now, with everything back to the default positions, mostly on top of each other, and wires going everywhere.

---

To reproduce, make sure that Jack is running, then start Carla and add some plugins just for something to connect.  Doesn't matter which plugins.  Go to the Patchbay, move things around, and drag some wires from outputs to inputs and vice-versa.

[image]

Now save it.  An older version (2.1.0) would create both a `carxp` and a `json` with the same name.  Instead, my current version (2.4.2) only creates the `carxp`.  Close Carla, confirm close, reopen, and load the `carxp`.  The older version would restore the positions in the patchbay, but the current version has them all messed up again.

[image]

I tried copying the `json` from an old backup, thinking that if it was there it might still read it, but it didn't make any difference.

Anyone know to make it remember the positions?

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour in Carla 2.4.2 in Ubuntustudio 22.04. I'd say this is a bug. It makes the software almost useless.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue, see [here](https://github.com/falkTX/Carla/issues/1666) or [here](https://github.com/falkTX/Carla/issues/1687). I just tried version 2.5.1 from the backports ppa, no improvement at all for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing similar problems. For me, The analog connections are retained, but not the location of the plugins on the screen. When I look at the XML file, I don't see that any positional information is stored, so I figure that's a design/implementation issue, not a bug.

But, my midi connections are rarely reconnected properly.